# Permission error when unzipping files that are password protected

Tags: python, windows, extract, unzip, zip

I am trying to unzip a number of files that are password protected but I keep getting some permission error. I have tried to perform this operation running vscode as an administrator but I am still getting the same error.

Here is the code:

```
input_file = ".\\pa-dirty-price-crawler\\folders"

import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(input_file, pwd=b'qpsqpwsr')
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/usr/workspace/pa-dirty-price-crawler/src/outlook.py", line 23, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.\\pa-dirty-price-crawler\\folders'
```

I do not know of another library that can do this same operation but if anyone has suggestions in regards to getting this fixed I would really appreciate it.

**Edit:**

When I try to specify the entire file path name as so:

```
input_file = "C:\\Users\\usr\\workspace\\pa-dirty-price-crawler\\folders"

import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(pwd=b'qpsqpwsr')
```

I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/usr/workspace/pa-dirty-price-crawler/src/outlook.py", line 23, in <module>
    with zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1240, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\usr\\workspace\\pa-dirty-price-crawler\\folders'
```

Comment: Your example code looks like your input is a directory not a zip file. Then you're trying to extract to the same directory. Are you sure your example is correct?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes that string works when I put in that password manually.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I am not sure if it is correct should I leave the path for the extract file none for now?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Could you see my edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing a directory as the input. This is the likely problem, not that the zip is password protected.

To extract a **zip** file, `zipfile.ZipFile` takes a zip file as an input not a directory.

Therefore, your code needs two variables: an input zip **file** and an **output** directory:

```
input_file = r".\pa-dirty-price-crawler\folders\myzipfile.zip"
output_directory = r".\pa-dirty-price-crawler\folders"

import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(input_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(output_directory, pwd=b'qpsqpwsr')
```

** note the use of `r"string"`, this helps having to escape all your back slashes*

Comment: That worked, than you very much. Although is it possible to do this for multiple zip files instead of specifying the \myzipfile.zip in the input_file path

Comment: I hope my question made sense there

Comment: Use `Path.glob("directory/*.zip")` with a `for` loop